# I'm losing my domain, is there any way I can redirect to new website?

Tags: redirect, web-hosting, http-redirect

So after 25 years of running www.unixnerd.demon.co.uk I have to change it to www.unixnerd.co.uk as Vodaphone are ditching all old Demon users. The site is one of the oldest BMW resources on the internet, it has loads of links and a good page rank.

Pardon my ignorance, but is there some way I can redirect traffic to the new site without the ability to host the old domain name?

If this question is inappropriate and someone cancels it PLEASE give me some guidance as to reposting it correctly. I have little knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I do not see a solution around keeping your domain. Here is the relevant code towards building a page to redirect to your website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;URL=http://www.unixnerd.co.uk">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NEW ADDRESS</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Our site has moved to a new address. Please note the change of address." >

    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style>

        body{
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', Arial, serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
            line-height: 1.618em;
            background: #464646 url('car1.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        h2{
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', Arial, serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size:40px;
            line-height: 1.618em;
        }
        section{
            max-width:800px;
            margin:8% auto 1em auto;
            background-color:#222;
            opacity: 0.8;
            filter: alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            color:#fff;
            padding:1em 5%;
        }

        a{
            color: #00CC66;
        }
        a:focus{
            outline:none;
            outline-offset:inherit;
        }
        @media (max-device-width: 1027px) {

            body{
                text-align:center;
                font-size:larger;
            }
            section{
                max-width: 90%;
            }

        }

        @media (max-device-width: 640px) {
            section{
                max-width: 97%;
            }

        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section>
    <h2>Our Site has moved!</h2>

    <h3>The service you want to use can be reached at <a href="www.unixnerd.co.uk">www.unixnerd.co.uk</a></h3>
    <h3>...You will be transferred to the new site in a moment...</h3>

    <p>If you have waited more than a few seconds and you are still seeing this message, please click on the link above! Thank you.</p>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

things to note* 
1. download an image from https://www.pexels.com/search/website%20background/
2. place the image in the same directory as your index file (where this html code is located)
3. under the styling tags, look for

```
            font-family: 'Noto Sans', Arial, serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
            line-height: 1.618em;
            background: #464646 url('car1.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

and change 
`background: #464646 url('car1.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;`

to the name of the picture file you downloaded and its extension.

This should redirect to your page automatically in ten seconds, and it should still keep professional integrity.

Answer (score 1):

If the domain still functions, you could add a page as an index explaining that your site has migrated to a new domain name with a link. If this is a route you want to go towards, I am happy to provide you the page to use as the index in this discussion. As for the page rank, your website should already have a decent page rank minus the traffic. The people who are actively viewing your site and that see your link to the new domain name will help you gain the traction back and help you score higher on the search rankings. EDIT: I have visited your website that will soon be deprecated, a few things to mention is that you want to add an SSL ticket and use better layout practices to score higher on search rankings. You still have time now to add the index page to redirect traffic to your new website.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that website shows it's age in many places. Been running since 1996. Sadly I won't have access to the original domain for much longer, I will put in a redirect to the new site soon though. Not having access to the old domain after May is my big problem.